# WiFi Repeater on a open WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I am not sure if this would work. I am working at a place that has open WiFi but the signal is to weak to log in. I would like to installed a WiFi repeater to boost the signal, but the open WiFi has a user agreement page that I have to type in my email then check a agreement box to log on. Is there a way to run a script to automatically type the email and check the box to log into the WiFi, with in the WiFi repeater? Netgear WN2000RPT v1

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you would have to run a script on the Netgear extender.

You just install the extender. Connect to the new network it creates and configure it to connect to the original open network.

If you then try to access the Internet you should see the login page with user agreement box on your computer. Just log in as you normally would.

If the extender bridges the original network correctly you should get an ip address in the range of the original network and each client connecting to the extended network should get the agreement page before being able to go online.

Keep in mind that the extender will only have one internal radio that will have to send and receive all packets to and from the original access point. Because an access point radio  cannot send and receive at the same time, this will effectively half the maximum potential throughput compared to being directly connecting to the original access point.

Comment: *"the extender will only have one internal radio that will have to send and receive all packets to and from the original access point"* I assume you're referring to the specific model as mentioned in the question? Dual-band extenders could easily work around this problem.

Comment: That is correct, a dual-band extender will be able to extend a 2.4 ghz and a 5 ghz network at the same time. So as long as you use it in a way that the original and extended network operate in a different frequency band, you would not have that problem. Your biggest penalty would be some added latency.

Comment: Well here is the problem, I can get almost all the way through the configurations but then it stop, because it can not establish a actual connection to the Internet. I have tried multiple times but it still doesn't work.